# Activate ZFS Snapshots

Tags: zfs

I accidentally delete some files from my zfs pool and tried to mount the latest snapshots but i just figured out that i have no snapshots. How to activate the snapshots, how to configure it?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.1 server and zfs 0.6.1, pool version is 28.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have not taken any snapshots, you lost your data.

To take snapshot, use `zfs snapshot` command

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbcya/index.html

Answer (score 27):

Starting from Ubuntu 17.04 you can install zfs-auto-snapshot like this:

```
sudo apt install zfs-auto-snapshot
```

For Ubuntu versions prior 17.04 you could setup [zfs-auto-snapshot](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs-auto-snapshot) to use automatic snapshots from repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zfs-native/stable; sudo apt-get install zfs-auto-snapshot
```

or directly from github

```
curl -L https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs-auto-snapshot/archive/master.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp/
pushd /tmp/zfs-auto-snapshot-master && sudo make install && popd && rm -rf /tmp/zfs-auto-snapshot-master
```

By default it creates snapshots for each data set every 15 minutes and saves snapshot up to 1 year. However you could disable snapshots for specific dataset by setting `com.sun:auto-snapshot` dataset property to false

```
sudo zfs set com.sun:auto-snapshot=false tank/tmp
```

You could also use `com.sun:auto-snapshot:...` properties to tune auto snapshot behaviour. E.g. save snapshots daily for 31 days for tank/backup dataset:

```
sudo zfs set com.sun:auto-snapshot=true tank/backup
sudo zfs set com.sun:auto-snapshot:monthly=false tank/backup
sudo zfs set com.sun:auto-snapshot:weekly=false tank/backup
sudo zfs set com.sun:auto-snapshot:daily=true tank/backup
sudo zfs set com.sun:auto-snapshot:hourly=false tank/backup
sudo zfs set com.sun:auto-snapshot:frequent=false tank/backup
```

By default script saves:

- frequent snapshots every 15 mins, keeping 4 snapshots
- hourly snapshots every hour, keeping 24 snapshots
- daily snapshots every day, keeping 31 snapshots
- weekly snapshots every week, keeping 7 snapshots
- monthly snapshots every month, keeping 12 snapshots

Comment: You can also install using the prepackaged ZFS repo: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zfs-native/stable; sudo apt-get install zfs-auto-snapshot`

Comment: Thank you Scott! I've added information about repository to the answer.

Comment: The PPA is only available for trusty.

Comment: Now in 2021 ,  zfs-auto-snapshot is in the main repo, no extra work required.