# How to stop ZFS?

Tags: 20.04, zfs

So during installation, I decided to try out ZFS. Initially it looked good, but it is taking up way too much space on my 60 GB SSD. How do I stop snapshots and delete existing ones? I am using ubuntu 20.04 and I am new to the linux world (migrating from windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list snapshots:

```
zfs list -t snapshot
```

To delete snapshots:

```
zfs destroy pool/fs@snapshot
```

which you got from the first command.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

To completely stop snapshoting you need to clear com.sun:auto-snapshot property

```
sudo zfs set com.sun:auto-snapshot=false tank/backup
```

Actually, it makes sense to tune other snapshot related properties. See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/391970/226234) to another snapshot related question.